# Dynamically Add Accordion onClick ReactJS Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to have accordions with dropdowns instead of title which can be added dynamically when we click on button.

The problem is, even though i can add N number of accordions i cannot select or change the dropdown values of each accordion.

Here it is on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-driscoll-k5t26?file=/src/Panel.js)

Answer (score 0):

after going through line by line, its now fixed, Here it is on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-driscoll-k5t26?file=/src/Panel.js)